# positive root of the equation $x^2+x-3-\sqrt{3}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$x^2+x-3-\sqrt{3}=0$
using the quadratic formula we get 
$$x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$ for the positive root

but the actual answer is simply   $x=\sqrt3$

I am unable to perform the simplification any help would we helpful

Comment: Hint: write $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}=a+b\sqrt3$ and compare terms.

Comment: $13+4\sqrt 3=13+2\sqrt{12}=(12+1)+2\sqrt{12\times 1}=(\sqrt{12}+\sqrt 1)^2$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel we would have to square both sides to obtain a and b which might give 2 sets of values for (a,b)?

Answer (score 8):

$13+4\sqrt{3}=(2\sqrt{3})^2+2(2\sqrt{3})(1)+1=(2\sqrt{3}+1)^2$

So it is just $\dfrac{-1+2\sqrt{3}+1}{2}$.

---

We may also start from the original equation.

\begin{align*}
x^2+x-3-\sqrt{3}&=0\\
x^2-3+x-\sqrt{3}&=0\\
(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})+x-\sqrt{3}&=0\\
(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3}+1)&=0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\sqrt{3}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x^2+x-3-\sqrt{3}=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2+x=3+\sqrt{3}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x^2+x=a^2+a\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
So by inspection, we get the solution $x=a$.

By Vieta's formula, the sum of the roots is $-1$, so the other root is $-1-a$, which is negative.

Thus, $x=\sqrt{3}$ is the only positive root.

Alternatively,
\begin{align*}
&x^2+x=a^2+a\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(x^2-a^2)+(x-a)=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&(x-a)(x+a+1)=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x=a\;\,\text{or}\;\,x=-1-a\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x=\sqrt{3}\;\,\text{or}\;\,x=-1-\sqrt{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so as before, $x=\sqrt{3}$ is the only positive root.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(1+ 2 \sqrt3)^2 = 1 + 4 \sqrt 3 + 4 \cdot \sqrt 3^2 = 13 + 4 \sqrt 3$. The expression is now easy to simplify.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than pulling $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}=1+2\sqrt3$ magically out of a hat, write $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}=a+b\sqrt3,$

as suggested by [Parcly Taxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel) in a comment.  Squaring both sides, $13+4\sqrt3=(a^2+3b^2)+2ab\sqrt3.$

$13=a^2+3b^2$ and $4=2ab$ means $b=2/a$ and $13=a^2+\dfrac{12}{a^2},$ i.e., $a^4-13a^2+12=0$, i.e., $(a^2-1)(a^2-12)=0$, i.e., $a=\pm1$ or $a=\pm2\sqrt3$ and respectively $b=\pm2$ or $\pm\dfrac 1{\sqrt3}.  $  Note that $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}>0.$  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'd be interested to know why the downvotes

Comment: My two cents: I upvoted it. Perhaps, the answer can be improved on with more explanations, i.e. a and b are positive from the get-go, which shortens things. I mean you can't have both a and b negative or of opposite signs. It might be confusing to some but that's not the reason to vote it down. It should make the student think more thoroughly (why a and be are positive). You are making a good contribution to the website IMO.